# General proof of Green's theorem

Tags: calculus

We know that Green's theorem is true for any region bounded by a piecewise smooth, simple closed curve in a plane. But how to prove this? Every proof I find online assumes $D$ can be decomposed into finitely many type III regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof for a region bounded by a rectifiable Jordan curve is done in the *first edition* of Apostol's Mathematical Analysis. See Theorem 10-43.